# angular-6-datatable sorting rows per page and pagination not working

Tags: datatable, angular6

Just as the title states, I just cannot get this to work. It seems so simple. I just follow the instructions on [this link to the npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable)

The following is some bs data that I made:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Austin to Carls 32 to 33 chocolates to oil",
    "price": "9.67",
    "category": "oils",
    "ts": "2019-01-06 19:31:45",
    "product_image_id": "33",
    "enabled": "0",
    "product_image": "Austin-183-84-62-carlsbad.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "something test 3 upd",
    "price": "12.23",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 06:54:40",
    "product_image_id": "28",
    "enabled": "0",
    "product_image": "40-64-grand-canyon.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "Test post this.productModel",
    "price": "24.96",
    "category": "toys",
    "ts": "2019-01-06 19:36:59",
    "product_image_id": "34",
    "enabled": "0",
    "product_image": "roswell-285-40-arizona.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "name": "test 5",
    "price": "3.42",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 08:06:11",
    "product_image_id": "35",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "grand-canyon-northridge.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "name": "Test post to not dup empty row",
    "price": "4.56",
    "category": "candles",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 08:29:50",
    "product_image_id": "36",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "40-64-grand-canyon.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "name": "testing",
    "price": "4.57",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 08:39:02",
    "product_image_id": "37",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "Austin-183-84-62-carlsbad.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "name": "test 4 post dubs",
    "price": "6.72",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 08:48:17",
    "product_image_id": "38",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "carlsbad-285-roswell.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "19",
    "name": "test 5 isset post",
    "price": "6.78",
    "category": "toys",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 09:46:37",
    "product_image_id": "40",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "first-ent-rent-ridgegate.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "name": "test 5 isset post to update",
    "price": "6.78",
    "category": "toys",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 09:47:49",
    "product_image_id": "40",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "first-ent-rent-ridgegate.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "23",
    "name": "testing product w jwt",
    "price": "12.34",
    "category": "toys",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 13:51:08",
    "product_image_id": "30",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "crater-winslow-40.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "24",
    "name": "testing product w jwt",
    "price": "12.34",
    "category": "toys",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 13:52:22",
    "product_image_id": "30",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "crater-winslow-40.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "25",
    "name": "testing product w jwt",
    "price": "12.34",
    "category": "toys",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 13:56:19",
    "product_image_id": "30",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "crater-winslow-40.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "26",
    "name": "test with jwt from app",
    "price": "8.34",
    "category": "candles",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 15:55:31",
    "product_image_id": "44",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "app-comp-return-url-local-storage-getItem.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "27",
    "name": "test 10 jwt",
    "price": "10.56",
    "category": "oils",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 22:24:07",
    "product_image_id": "45",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "return-url-local-storage-setItem.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "28",
    "name": "test 11 jwt",
    "price": "10.99",
    "category": "toys",
    "ts": "2019-01-05 22:30:13",
    "product_image_id": "46",
    "enabled": "0",
    "product_image": "app-comp-return-url-local-storage-getItem.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "29",
    "name": "Some new prod testing enabled",
    "price": "1.99",
    "category": "candles",
    "ts": "2019-01-06 19:40:14",
    "product_image_id": "48",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "business_cards_2.png"
  }
]
```

BTW, this is the data from console.log that was JSON.stringyfied, which is what was returned from the db

The following is from the component in the constructor, where I retrieve the data from the db:

```
this.prdSrvc.getAllProducts().subscribe(resProd => {
  this.mfData = this.filteredProductsObj = this.productsObj =
    resProd.products;
  console.log("resProd.products: ", JSON.stringify(resProd.products));
});
this.mfActivePage = 1;
this.mfRowsOnPage = 5;
this.mfSortBy = "names";
```

The following is the html to display the data, which does the display the data, but it displays all of it.

```
<table
  class="table table-striped"
  [mfData]="mfData"
  #mf="mfDataTable"
  [mfRowsOnPage]="mfRowsOnPage"
>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 20%">
        <mfDefaultSorter by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 50%">
        <mfDefaultSorter by="email">Price</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10%">
        <mfDefaultSorter by="age">Category</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 20%">
        <mfDefaultSorter by="city">Thumbnail</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mfData">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{ item.category | uppercase }}</td>
      <td>
        <img
          height="100px"
          src="{{ oshopUrl + 'uploads/' + item.product_image }}"
          alt=""
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <mfBootstrapPaginator
          [rowsOnPageSet]="[5, 10, 25]"
        ></mfBootstrapPaginator>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I do not understand what I could be doing wrong. This should be so easy. I have tried the productsObj as data, along with the filteredProductsObj (only products enabled), but it is just not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make everything work, by making the following changes.

First, I declared the following variable:

```
  data;
```

Second, I set this variable to the object returning from the service and I placed everything within the ngOnInit method:

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.prdSrvc.getAllProducts().subscribe(resProd => {
    this.data = this.filteredProductsObj = this.productsObj =
      resProd.products;
    // console.log("resProd.products: ", JSON.stringify(resProd.products));
  });
  this.mfActivePage = 1;
  this.mfRowsOnPage = 5;
  this.mfSortBy = "names";
}
```

Updated the html to the following, specifically let item of mf.data. Also, my sort was originally off because I was still using the original template from the web site. I had to change to match my object - for instance, mfDefaultSorter by="product_image"

```
<table
class="table table-striped"
[mfData]="filteredProductsObj"
#mf="mfDataTable"
[mfRowsOnPage]="mfRowsOnPage"
>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 20%">
      <mfDefaultSorter by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 50%">
      <mfDefaultSorter by="price">Price</mfDefaultSorter>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 10%">
      <mfDefaultSorter by="category">Category</mfDefaultSorter>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 20%">
      <mfDefaultSorter by="product_image">Thumbnail</mfDefaultSorter>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ item.category | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>
      <img
        height="100px"
        src="{{ oshopUrl + 'uploads/' + item.product_image }}"
        alt=""
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <mfBootstrapPaginator
        [rowsOnPageSet]="[5, 10, 25]"
      ></mfBootstrapPaginator>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```